# GestureRecognizer doesnt work dynamic/in extra class swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uigesturerecognizer

I want to implement a gesture recognizer for every Viewcontroller.

The following code is working:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
   func draggedView(sender:UIPanGestureRecognizer){
    // do stuff
   }

   override func viewDidLoad() {
     super.viewDidLoad()

     let panRec = UIPanGestureRecognizer()
     panRec.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ViewController.draggedView(_:)))
     self.view.addGestureRecognizer(panRec)
     self.view.userInteractionEnabled = true   
     }
}
```

Now I want give this pan gesture a little bit more dynamic/abstraction

```
   class Tools : NSObject {

   var currentViewController: UIViewController? 

   func addPanToViewController(viewcontroller: UIViewController) {

    currentViewcontroller = viewcontroller

    if let currentViewcontroller = currentViewcontroller {
        let panRec = UIPanGestureRecognizer()
        panRec.addTarget(self, action: #selector(draggedView(_:)))
        currentViewcontroller.view.addGestureRecognizer(panRec)
        currentViewcontroller.view.userInteractionEnabled = true  
    } 

   }

 func draggedView(sender:UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
  //never called
 }
}
```

I call the code in the ViewController-Class like this:

```
    let sidemenu = Tools()
    sidemenu.addPanToViewController(self)
```

But nothing happens. No Error, but no gestures are working. With the debugger I see that the gesture was added. So every code get executed.

I want execute the draggedView inside my Tools class.

I really don't understand where my problem is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think if you want this to work, you have to make the Tools class become singleton with:

`static let sharedInstance = Tools()`

then in the `addPanToViewController`:

`panRec.addTarget(Tools.sharedInstance, action:#selector(draggedView(_:)))`

In your `viewController`:

`Tools.sharedInstance.addPanToViewController(self)`

Comment: Doesnt workt for me. I don't want execute the draggedView inside my Viewcontroller. 
The draggedView should execute in Tools

Comment: Yes, this code is for that, i tried with NStimer selector and it work, check for edit, i think i forgot to delete some code, this will execute the `draggedView ` in Tools class

Comment: Now I got it. Your code is working. Thanks for that. Can you explain me why? In my variant it seems that my reference to viewcontroller got lost... or? But why?

Answer (score 0):

```
currentViewcontroller.delegete = your gesturerecogniser delegate
```

Comment: Could u give me a litte more information? At the moment I didn't use delegates. So I have to set a delegate inside mit ViewController class? Which kind of delegate? 
Should I use the UIGestureRecognizerDelegate inside my Tools class?

Comment: Yes. you have to invoke UIGestureRecognizerDelegate. then you can write currentViewcontroller.delegete = self

Comment: But this execute the draggedView inside the Viewcontroller or not?

Comment: do you want gesture in draggedView or on ViewController?

Comment: On Viewcontroller. The problem is, draggedView should do always the same for a bunch of Viewcontroller. It should do UI Actions on the UIViewcontroller.

Comment: if you want action on UIViewController on pan gesture then set gesture delegate properly and add target action after adding pan gesture to the view or viewcontroller